# Swap places in business class with friend

Tags: business-travel

Question to experienced travelers in both economy and business classes. I fly for work, in business. My daughter is flying privately, same flight, in economy. Long transpacific flight. Daughter never flew business, and I’d love to give her such possibility. But I can’t pay 5000 dollars for her business upgrade...

Do you think we could just swap boarding passes and places?
A year ago same situation happened with my son  and flight staff didn’t allow to swap.

But with 2 women - how will they know?
Thanks

Comment: What do you expect us to say? The crew might spot the subterfuge, or they might not. They might turn a blind eye, or they might not. I don't see how we can give any sort of meaningful answer to this.

Comment: The short answer is that the cabin crew certainly does not want anyone swapping in the middle of the flight, or for one person to loiter in the other cabin to visit mid-flight. If each passenger intends to stay in his or her seat and cabin for the entire duration, however, it's unlikely they will know or care.

Comment: Swapping places mid-flight might be troublesome.  Swap boarding passes in the jetway: after passing through the boarding gate but before you actually get on the plane.  Unless the airline checks your passport again, they probably would not notice.

Comment: Welcome new user @Emma.  it's a great question.  You absolutely can not and won't get away with swapping ***during*** the flight.  But if you simply swap "as you get on board" you will be 100% OK.  Exactly as Nick says simply swap passes in the jetway.   Don't make a big fuss.  Say nothing. It's a great plan for your daughter, enjoy!

Comment: hi @CannonFodder .  I can't really agree with your comment.  This is a totally commonplace thing which 1000s of people have done numerous times.  (Indeed, it has a perfectly clear and factual answer which has been given.)  Any number of people, including even F.A.s, could give actual factual info on this.  So its' a fine question. (I just commented rather than answered, since it's a dupe anyway.)

Comment: @Fattie Please don't post answers as comments. It completely bypasses all our quality control mechanism.s

Comment: hi @DavidRicherby !  Sorry, were you addressing me or the people who posted answers as comments?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in this answer: [Are you allowed to swap seats with a friend in a different booking class?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124692/are-you-allowed-to-swap-seats-with-a-friend-in-a-different-booking-class)

It's against the official "rules" but the flight crew has the leeway to allow it. You can always ask nicely but it's going to be hit or miss and there is no way to predict the outcome.